# Change visibility settings in onPostexecute in async task

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, visibility, android-progressbar

I'm using a `AsyncTask` to parse data from a website via Jsoup. Within my layout (fragment) I want to display a `ProgressBar` till the data is loaded. After the data is loaded I want to change visibility of the `ProgressBar` to `INVISIBLE` and visibility of the `ScrollView` to `VISIBLE` (to show the data). I tried it in the onPostExecute() method, but it doesn`t work.

```
private class Erste extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private ScrollView scrollView;

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        progressBar.findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        progressBar.setVisibility(progressBar.INVISIBLE);
        scrollView.findViewById(R.id.tabelle1);
        scrollView.setVisibility(scrollView.VISIBLE);
    ...

}
```

Comment: Incorrect ids assigned to views.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should make your `ProgressBar` VISIBLE on `preExecute` method and the `ScrollView` INVISIBLE. After the `doInBackground` has finished, you should do what you ask for. The opposite.

Answer (score 0):

No object is assigned at progressBar and scrollView. You should try something like this...

```java
private class Erste extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private ScrollView scrollView;

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        progressBar.setVisibility(progressBar.INVISIBLE);
        scrollView = findViewById(R.id.tabelle1);
        scrollView.setVisibility(scrollView.VISIBLE);
...}
```